# Ionic: There are multiple entries in the deeplink config with the segment

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I work with ionic 3.everything worked well until now. When i run the command `ionic serve`. I got this error:

```
Error: There are multiple entries in the deeplink config with the segment of player
    at BuildError.Error (native)
    at new BuildError (/projects/igamers/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at /projects/igamers/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/deep-linking.js:57:21
```

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have multiple `@IonicPage` with same `segment`.

Segment names should be unique. If you know don't provide `segment` it will take `@IonicPage`'s `name` as `segment`.

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'my-page',
  segment: 'some-path'
})
```